# How to hide Docker volumes from Dolphin file manager?

Tags: docker, kde-plasma-5, dolphin-file-manager

KDE Plasma user here.

Dolphin file manager is displaying all my Docker volumes in its `devices` sidebar section, and I'd like to prevent them to appear here without having to manually hide them.

[image]

Is there some way to do so? Or to filter out devices based in their path (all Docker volumes come from `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<hash>`)

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this; did you ever find one?

Comment: No, I'm still waiting

Comment: Looks like it's a bug with Docker, which others have reported here: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1096